# Get the number of objects that is referenced in two tables

Tags: django

I have following two models. I want to get the *number* of user objects that are in both tables.

```
class Share(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    # more code

class Follow(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User)
    followee = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # more code
```

Now

```
shares = Share.objects.filter(blog=some_blog)
follows = Follow.objects.filter(followee=some_user)

share_users = [share.user for share in shares]
followers = [follow.follower for follow in follows]

unique_count = len(set(share_users + followers))
```

This is obviously horrible way to get `unique_count`. What could be a better way to get this count?

Comment: Do you mean get the unique user count for Share+follow ?

Comment: yes, I want unique user count for both the models

Comment: sorry about the variable name, updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

First set `related_name` for the conflicting types

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="follower")
    followee = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="followee")
```

and then, using [`Q objects`,](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) you can do something like this

```
from django.db.models import Q
unique_user_count = User.objects.filter(
                         Q(share__isnull=False) 
                       | Q(follower__isnull=False) 
                       | Q(followee__isnull=False)).distinct().count()
```

Comment: That is it. I didn't know about Q objects. Thanks!

Comment: OK, this gets the unique user count for the whole Follow+Share. How about for just a specific blog and specific followee (`len(set(followers) & set(share_users))`)? How do I specify them in the filter? like

Comment: i dont have access to  a computer right now. You can just create a new question, so someone can help you.